# py2neo: Make Deep Copy of Node and Store it Locally

Tags: neo4j, nodes, deep-copy, py2neo

Is it possible to make a deep copy of a node object and store it in any ordinary container (like a list) and not in the neo4j database? What I need to do is make a copy of a node that I retrieve form the data base, then modify certain properties of the copy and store it temporarily. And only later merge it into the data base.

Answer (score 0):

Py2neo `Node` objects have an `unbind` method that will detach the node from its remote counterpart (in the database). So you can fetch some Node objects, unbind them, and save them to a list:

```
node_list = []
for node in graph.find("Person"):
    node.unbind()
    node_list.append(node)

node_list
------------
[<Node labels={'Person'} properties={'name': 'Jim'}>,
<Node labels={'Person'} properties={'name': 'Anna'}>,
<Node labels={'Person'} properties={'name': 'Sally'}>,
<Node labels={'Person'} properties={'name': 'Joe'}>,
<Node labels={'Person'} properties={'name': 'Bob'}>,
<Node labels={'Person'} properties={'name': 'Mike'}>,
<Node labels={'Person'} properties={'name': 'Billy'}>]
```

Node object also support pickle serialization / deserialization:

```
import pickle
pickle.dump(node_list, open("nodes.p", "wb"))
node_list_from_pickle = pickle.load(open("nodes.p", "rb"))

node_list_from_pickle
---------------------
[<Node labels={'Person'} properties={'name': 'Jim'}>,
<Node labels={'Person'} properties={'name': 'Anna'}>,
<Node labels={'Person'} properties={'name': 'Sally'}>,
<Node labels={'Person'} properties={'name': 'Joe'}>,
<Node labels={'Person'} properties={'name': 'Bob'}>,
<Node labels={'Person'} properties={'name': 'Mike'}>,
<Node labels={'Person'} properties={'name': 'Billy'}>]
```

Node objects contain a LabelSet (which is a subclass of `set`) and PropertySet (which is a subclass of `dict`) so if you really wanted to do a deepcopy you would just need to grab these two objects within a Node instance.